# firebase users login through mobile

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to know if it's possible for a mobile registered firebase user to log-in without authentication procedure, in other words:

Lets say an administrator creates a firebase user by console (or web interface to console) then is it possible that when this user launches the app on his mobile he just logs in without the authentication procedure?

To put it simple, is it possible for mobile users a log-in like  email/password user: just enter the number and log-in?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "just enter the number and login"? Which "number" are you referring to?

Comment: @ChrisEdgington, his mobile number the one the administrator used for sign him in into firebase user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to using a Phone Number for authentication this is supported by Firebase and the documentation can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

The caveat to this is that you can't create a user through the Firebase console as you were suggesting. It relies on the user using their mobile number to register when they logging in for the first time.

The other option that may or may not be applicable is to use Anonymous authentication along with a collection of predefined users with numbers as Peter suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new users from the console, first you need to enable the email/password Sign in method. Then you can add a new user:

[image]

Then the user can login using the email/password added in the console.

If you want the user to enter a number and login, then associate a number in the firebase database with the email:

```
Users
  userid
     email: userx@gmail.com
     number: 102
```

Comment: ok but in this case the user won't be logged, i mean if i open the console and look into authentication there won't be "last log in time" for that user or, even worst, "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()" will return null. if possible i'd like to avoid duplications but, of course, if there's no better way i'll do something like that.